# Why do I see THROW in a C library?

Tags: c++, c, exception, header-files

When I do:
`less /usr/include/stdio.h` (which is only a C library - nothing to do with C++)

I see `__THROW` after quite a few function declarations.
Also, comments above a few functions say that 'This function is a possible cancellation point and therefore not marked with `__THROW`'
What is all this for?

`throw` is meant to be for exception handling...but as far as I know, C doesn't provide any support for it.

Please explain.

Comment: Which compiler? Looks like GCC to me. (Keep in mind there is no "the standard library", so it's helpful to specify which implementation you use.)

Comment: Ahh, I see you've discovered glibc :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This header is likely shared between the C and C++ compiler for that vendor. Did you look what `__THROW` is defined as?

I suspect something akin to:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define __THROW throw()
#else
    #define __THROW
#endif
```

Or for actual specifications:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define __THROW(x) throw(x)
#else
    #define __THROW(x)
#endif
```

As you can see, in a C build, it expands to nothing. In C++, it does what you expect. This allows vendors to reuse the same file.

---

Just to nitpick, this isn't entirely true: *"(which is only a C library - nothing to do with C++)"*

The C++ standard library includes the ability to use the C standard library. The actual header is `<cxxx>` where `xxx` is the C header name. That is, to include the C header `<stdlib.h>` in C++, you do `<cstdlib>`. So it does have to do with C++. :)

This is why you see the code you do. Duplicating the header for two different languages would be a nightmare for maintenance and cleanliness.

Comment: The __THROW macro is defined as follows: if not defined __cplusplus #define __THROW  __attribute__ (( __nothrow__ __LEAF)). and if the __cplusplus is defined then __THROW is extend to throw(). __LEAF is defined as follows: #define __LEAF , __leaf__

Comment: That is true if  __GNUC__ was defined, otherwise __THROW is extend for nothing in c and c++

Answer (score 11):

You can do

```
cpp -include stdlib.h -dM /dev/null  |grep '#define __THROW '
```

to learn what it actually expands to.

On my system, I get:

```
#define __THROW __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ __LEAF))
```

The **nothrow** and **leaf** attributes are described at 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes
as follows:

**leaf**

> leaf Calls to external functions with this attribute must return to
>   the current compilation unit only by return or by exception handling.
>   In particular, a leaf function is not allowed to invoke callback
>   functions passed to it from the current compilation unit, directly
>   call functions exported by the unit, or longjmp into the unit. Leaf
>   functions might still call functions from other compilation units and
>   thus they are not necessarily leaf in the sense that they contain no
>   function calls at all. The attribute is intended for library functions
>   to improve dataflow analysis. The compiler takes the hint that any
>   data not escaping the current compilation unit cannot be used or
>   modified by the leaf function. For example, the sin function is a leaf
>   function, but qsort is not.
>
> Note that leaf functions might indirectly run a signal handler defined
>   in the current compilation unit that uses static variables. Similarly,
>   when lazy symbol resolution is in effect, leaf functions might invoke
>   indirect functions whose resolver function or implementation function
>   is defined in the current compilation unit and uses static variables.
>   There is no standard-compliant way to write such a signal handler,
>   resolver function, or implementation function, and the best that you
>   can do is to remove the leaf attribute or mark all such static
>   variables volatile. Lastly, for ELF-based systems that support symbol
>   interposition, care should be taken that functions defined in the
>   current compilation unit do not unexpectedly interpose other symbols
>   based on the defined standards mode and defined feature test macros;
>   otherwise an inadvertent callback would be added.
>
> The attribute has no effect on functions defined within the current
>   compilation unit. This is to allow easy merging of multiple
>   compilation units into one, for example, by using the link-time
>   optimization. For this reason the attribute is not allowed on types to
>   annotate indirect calls.

**nothrow**

> nothrow The nothrow attribute is used to inform the compiler that a
>   function cannot throw an exception. For example, most functions in the
>   standard C library can be guaranteed not to throw an exception with
>   the notable exceptions of qsort and bsearch that take function pointer
>   arguments.

What `__attribute__((nothrow))` means in C is answered at [gcc - what is attribute nothrow used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882645/gcc-what-is-attribute-nothrow-used-for) . Basically, it's for cooperation with C++ code, and you can use it if the function won't ever call back to exception-throwing C++ code.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your other question concerning "This function is a possible cancellation point and therefore not marked with __THROW": This deals with multi-threading. You can "cancel" a thread, but it won't actually "cancel" until it reaches a cancellation point. Some more info: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html

Comment: Thanks. Changed to another link entirely that still provides useful information.