# Are the parameters of a macro executed given the #define'ition ((void)0)?

Tags: c++, macros

I have the following macro in C++

```
#define AppLogExceptionIf(condition, ...) ((void) 0)
```

I was wondering whether the `condition` would still get executed? Am I right in thinking the expansion is equivalent to a

```
false;
```

statement regardless of the `condition`, eg:

```
AppLogExceptionIf(0 == (x = 5), "Big problem!");
```

Would not assign to `x`?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "executed". Macros are not executed, at least in the way I think about them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: Empty function macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187628/c-empty-function-macros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `condition` will not be evaluated. Wherever `AppLogExceptionIf` appears with parentheses and at least one argument after it will be textually replaced with `((void) 0)` before the compiler has a chance to see the code, and will do absolutely nothing, like you indicated that you thought.

Answer (score 3):

Macros are textually replaced, so the `condition` doesn't even appear in the source code after the preprocessor has treated it.

Comment: I think I remember, it's been so long since I actually _chose_ to write one.