# How to supress unused (void **arg) parameter?

Tags: c++, c, unused-variables

In the function below I'm not using the parameter (void **arg). But since it's unused inside the function compiler gives me the error below:

```
error: unused parameter 'arg' [-Werror=unused-parameter]
bool decodeString(pb_istream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void **arg)
```

I tried to suppress it by writing void(arg) inside the function without any luck.
Can anyone help me with the correct way?

Comment: Leave out the variable name: `bool decodeString(pb_istream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void **arg)` becomes `bool decodeString(pb_istream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void **)`

Comment: Side note: I prefer to comment out the name `bool decodeString(pb_istream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void ** /*arg*/ )` because the name may hold useful information about how the parameter should be used, should that information become important later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress "unused parameter" warnings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599160/how-to-suppress-unused-parameter-warnings-in-c)

Comment: @MadPhysicist only viable in C++. dbush's answer below works in C and C++. Mind you, my C is pretty stale. Might have changed.

Comment: @user4581301 - I 2nd the 2nd comment.

Comment: See [my answer to *Empty function macros*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187855/5987).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the parameter in an expression casted to `void`.  Then the parameter is "used".

```
bool decodeString(pb_istream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void **arg)
{
    (void)arg;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This does not work, found similar answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599160/how-to-suppress-unused-parameter-warnings-in-c and tried it before.

error: variable or field 'arg' declared void
void(arg);

Comment: Be *very* careful with doing this as conceptually you have induced a read of the value. Personally I'd comment `arg` - you don't lose the self-commenting nature of the function and you can always uncomment it if you need it. This is a good idiomatic (especially in C) technique though.  Although I do remember reading something about a nasty bug emanating from this, with gcc and optimisations turned up to the maximum. Might have dreamt it though.

Comment: @razz, if this doesn't work in C you have a second problem.

Comment: you can also `int decodeString(void **)
{ /* ... */
}`

Comment: @razz Then you typed something in wrong.  `(void)arg;` in the function body compiles without warning.

Comment: I see `void(arg)` called out as a failure in the question. You might have just bracketed the wrong term.

Comment: @user4581301 you're right! (void)arg works, my second problem is:
libboost_thread.so.1.68.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Comment: @razz That's a separate issue that should be in a separate question.