# what does "arguments cannot be accessed portably" means in a variadic argument syntax context?

Tags: c++, c++20, unreal

I'm working on Unreal 5.3 and I'm currently trying to understand variadic arguments / ellipsis operator in C++.
I'm Coming from self taught unity, C#, python so some stuff are hard to understand at first.

Especially i see in Unreal code lines like this all around that i dont understand yet:

```
#define UE_LOGFMT_LOC(...)
#define UE_LOGFMT_NSLOC(...)
#define UE_LOGFMT_LOC_EX(...)
#define UE_LOGFMT_NSLOC_EX(...)
```

i checked online and ended up reading this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments
but i don't understand what this line means:
`int printz(...); // valid, but the arguments cannot be accessed portably`

thanks !

Comment: Those are variadic macros. They have nothing to do with variadic functions.

Comment: You're reading the wrong thing. That's for `...` function (not macro) parameters (an old C-ism that's almost never used in modern C++). In a macro, you need `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: For more information about the variadic macro use, you can check this [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).

Comment: I see, so the empty macros lines are only used to nullify the logs when building non-debug binaries, much like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187628/empty-function-macros 

I should have included the conditionnal in the code snippet.
Anyway, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out in the comments, you started this journey by looking at macros, not functions, so your initial problem was unrelated to variadic functions.

However, you eventually landed on that page about variadic arguments and you found that bit about "arguments cannot be accessed portably", which is what this question is about, so this is what I will answer.

In order to ***portably*** access variadic arguments, you must use the `va_start()` macro.  This macro requires the first argument to be passed as a parameter. When your variadic function accepts only a '...', there is no first argument to pass to `va_start()`, therefore you cannot use `va_start()`, therefore you cannot access the arguments in a portable way.