# Macro without definition in C

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

What is the use/applicability of macro function without definition:

```
#ifndef __SYSCALL
#define __SYSCALL(a, b)
#endif
```

One can find this macro in Linux system in header file `/usr/include/asm/msr.h`

I also notice macro of following kind.

```
#define _M(x) x
```

And only reason to defined this kind of macro that I can think to make code uniform. like in [#define SOMETHING (1 << 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095350/define-something-1-0). Is there any other hidden(better) use of this kind of macros?

An answer with example will be very helpful. Also 
can someone provide me a text/link to read about this.

Comment: The __SYSCALL macro is only defined on some architectures.

Comment: What do you mean by make the code more uniform?

Comment: @Hogan Sorry I couldn't express clearly by Uniform I means like this [`#define something 1<<0`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095350/define-something-1-0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the most common case of a macro of this form:

```
#define _M(x) x
```

is to provide backwards compatibility for compilers that only supported the original K&R dialect of C, that predated the now-ubiquitous ANSI C dialect.  In the original K&R dialect of the language, function arguments were not specified when declaring the function.  In 1989, ANSI standardized the language and incorporated a number of improvements, including function prototypes that declared the number of type of arguments.

```
int f(int x, double y); /* ANSI C. K&R compilers would not accept this */

int f(); /* Function declared in the original K&R dialect */
```

While compilers that support the original K&R dialect of C are rare (or extinct) these days, a lot of software was written when both kinds of compilers needed to be supported, and macros provided an easy way to support both.  There are still a lot of headers laying about that provide this backwards compatibility.

To provide backwards compatibility for K&R compilers, many header files have the following:

```
#if ANSI_PROTOTYPES
#  define _P(x) x
#else
#  define _P(x) ()
#endif

...

int f _P((int x, double y));
```

If the `ANSI_PROTOTYPES` definition has been correctly set (either by the user or by some prior `#ifdef` logic), then you get the desired behavior:

- If ANSI_PROTOTYPES is defined, the definition expands to `int f(int x, double y)`.
- If ANSI_PROTOTYPES is not defined, the definition expands to `int f()`

Comment: Thanks sfstewman! your answer is really good. I added some more uses.

Comment: "*One of the most common case of a macro of this form...*" - is this argument still valid nowadays?

Comment: @icepack there aren't a lot of new headers being written this way, but it's one of the more common uses you see for macros of that form.  I can't think of a whole lot of other uses that I've seen for it.

Answer (score 4):

This is often used with conditional expressions to disable a macro by causing it to be preprocessed to nothing. For example (simplified):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define ASSERT(x) if(!(x)) { abort(); }
#else
#define ASSERT(x) /* nothing */
#endif
```

Comment: Such an "empty" function-like macro has lots of potential for trouble. Better define it to `((void) 0)` or `do {} while(0)`. Fuller discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306611/how-do-i-implement-no-op-macro-or-template-in-c

Answer (score 3):

Just a follow-up to my question.

I got good answers. but I am also adding some more helpful example where macros without definition are useful, one can find it helpful in future:

**(1)**: [*Why do I see THROW in a C library?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486386/why-do-i-see-throw-in-a-c-library?answertab=votes#tab-top)
uses to share header file between C and C++.  The macro name is `_THROW(x)`

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define __THROW(x) throw(x)
#else
    #define __THROW(x)
#endif
```

**(2)** [*to eliminate warnings when a function parameter isn't used:*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187628/c-empty-function-macros/9187855#9187855)
This use is for c++. In C it will cause [an error too few arguments](http://codepad.org/WbSlIXkc) But in [C++ it works with no error](http://codepad.org/HJQs184z): (*codepad linked*)

```
#define UNUSED(x)
int value = 0;
int foo(int UNUSED(value))
{
    return 42;
}
int main(){
   foo(value);
}
```

(*for this I added c++ tag in my question*)

Additionally,
**(3):** The use of `#define _M(x) x` is as follows, just to makes code line up uniformly:

```
/* Signed.  */
 # define INT8_C(c)      c
 # define INT16_C(c)     c
 # define INT32_C(c)     c
 # if __WORDSIZE == 64
 #  define INT64_C(c)    c ## L
 # else
 #  define INT64_C(c)    c ## LL
 # endif
```

the file is: [/usr/include/stdint.h](http://repo-genesis3.cbi.utsa.edu/crossref/ns-sli/usr/include/stdint.h.html)

Answer (score 1):

It means that code that uses that macro will conditionally preprocess away to nothing.

As simple examples, consider debug code, logging or assertions.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a debug macro or an platform macro.  For example lets say I have a debugger attached to INT3.  I might have this when I'm debugging

```
 #define debug() INT3()
```

Then to be safe I'll add this to production code (to make sure I took them all out)

```
 #define debug()
```

This looks like something similar

It could be that in some cases on some systems this code needs to make a call -- for example on a certain CPU architecture or OS. But on your system it is just no-oped.