# What does this syntax mean in the C language?

Tags: c, syntax

I just tried to read some source code in the C language.
I encountered with some weird syntax in the `<ctype.h>` file.

Can somebody please explain the syntax or give me some reference as to what it means?

```c
extern const unsigned short int **__ctype_b_loc (void)
     __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
```

I know it should be some definition for a global variable, but the syntax spread into 2 lines, and there is much extra stuff after the variable definition (after the `__ctype_b_loc`)

Comment: @SteveSummit But GPT's explanation is correct (at least I think it is to the best of my ability - so if it's wrong then that's going to be a good wake-up call for me).

Comment: `__THROW` is likely a macro that expands to an `__attribute__` directive. And `__attribute__` is a GCC and Clang extension to add information for the compiler.

Comment: Also note that the function declaration is for an internal function that you should never need to call. There are plenty of documentation, tutorials and examples about the `__attribute___` compiler directive. It shouldn't have been hard to find.

Comment: Yeah - you're all right, (sorry!)

Comment: Regardless of the correctness of this particular response, ChatGPT is banned from SO.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: @AliShabani Unfortunately, these days, system header files are not intended to be human readable.  (Once upon a time, checking them was a great way to learn about a function, but today, not so much.) The weird extra syntax there is a couple of function *attributes*.  If you don't know what a particular attribute means, in general you can safely ignore it.

Comment: @Ali Shabani,  If it was simply [`extern const unsigned short int **__ctype_b_loc (void);`](https://cdecl.org/?q=const+unsigned+short+int+**__ctype_b_loc+%28void%29%3B), would you want explanation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see THROW in a C library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486386/why-do-i-see-throw-in-a-c-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration is a function prototype with extra non portable attributes.  A function prototype has a trailing `;` instead of a function body surrounded by `{}`.  Function prototypes declare argument and return types.  The posted code defines the function `__ctype_b_loc` as taking no arguments and retuning a pointer to a pointer to `unsigned short int` objects that should not be modified:

```
extern const unsigned short int **__ctype_b_loc(void);
```

The `__THROW` identifier probably means the function can throw an exception when used in a C++ context.

The `__attribute__((__const__))` means the function is *pure*, ie: the value returned only depends on the arguments, and thus will be constant for the duration of the program.

This function is used as part of the implementation of the `<ctype.h>` system, it probably returns a pointer to internal data,  a set of arrays of flags and values used by the `isxxx(c)` and `toxxx(c)` macros defined in this header.

Answer (score 1):

This is function declaration, `extern` specifies that the definition of this function is provided in another source file or library, the function name is `__ctype_b_loc`, it takes no arguments `(void)` and returns a pointer to a pointer to an array of `unsigned short int`, the `const` means that the data it returns can't be modified so I guess this declaration is used internally by the C library implementation.

Comment: Good answer.  Maybe point out that `__THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));` is non-standard compiler extensions?

Comment: I didn't know that ignoring the `{}` is possible for function declartion. and my question was about the function body (maybe) not the declartion syntax. but tnx anyway.